# How to implement referential integrity here?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I got the following structure - which I admit is not ideal, but so much is built on that, tat I want to minimize changes.
I am not sure about how to properly **implement referential integrity between Documents and Delivery Adresses**. Can it be done here without using triggers ? The problem is that the addressNum can sometimes be Null in the Documents.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Clients](
    [IdClient] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Nom] [varchar](40) NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_Clients PRIMARY KEY (IdClient))
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ClientsDelivAdr](
    [IdClient] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [AdrNum] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Adresse] [varchar](200) NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ClientsAdrLivr] PRIMARY KEY (IdClient, AdrNum))

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Documents](
    [DocID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NoDoc] [char](9) NULL,
    [IdClient] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [AdrNum] [tinyint] NULL,
    [DateDoc] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DocID] PRIMARY KEY (DocId))
```

Some Clients have several Delivery Adresses, some have none.
So data looks like this:

```
Clients
Id   Name     Address 
---  ----     -------
AA   ClientA  addressA
BB   ClientB  qddressB
CC   ClientC  addressC


DeliveryAdresses
Client  Adr   Address
------  ---   -------
AA      1     shop1
AA      2     shop2
CC      1     shopx

Documents
DocId   Client  Addr  OrderDate
------- ------  ----  --------
1001    CC      1     5/5/2013
1002    AA      1     5/5/2013
1003    BB     (Null) 5/5/2013
```

Comment: What do you want to enforce?

Comment: I was going to have a bash at this but now Damien's involved I don't think I'll bother :)

Comment: Mostly prevent deletion of Delivery Adresses that have been used at least once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just use foreign keys as you would expect:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Documents](
    [DocID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NoDoc] [char](9) NULL,
    [IdClient] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [AdrNum] [tinyint] NULL,
    [DateDoc] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DocID] PRIMARY KEY (DocId),
CONSTRAINT FK_DOC_Clients FOREIGN KEY (IdClient)
     references Clients (IdClient),
CONSTRAINT FK_Doc_Addresses FOREIGN KEY (IdClient,AdrNum)
     references DeliveryAddresses (IdClient,AdrNum) )
```

If one or more column values in the referencing side of a foreign key is `NULL`, then the foreign key constraint is not checked. Conversely, there's no way to have `NULL` be a foreign key reference.

Comment: Looks great. I did not know about your remark. I keep you updated, many thanks.

Comment: @iDevlop BTW, this method of enforcing foreign keys is called MATCH SIMPLE but there are [others](http://wiki.burnsoft.net/KB58.ashx). MATCH SIMPLE tends to be most useful in practice and is the default (and often the only supported) for most DBMSes.